# View Controller dismissing and reappearing previous view Controller

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I am new to iOS development and Swift, I have issue with view controllers events, what is the event automatically should be called when the top view controller dismisses and previous view controller shown again?

Actually what I mean is I have view controller A and view controller B, I click one button (assume go B view controller) of view controller A and move for view controller B then doing some task of view controller B and click one button (assume go back) in that time I dismiss view controller B then application automatically show view controller A, In this situation I have to fire one method, but my problem is view controller A how is it knows that it will reappear to be displayed?

Comment: Use the viewWillAppear and viewWillDisappear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your case,

**View Controller A** knows that it reappears by implementing one of the `UIViewController` tow methods -depends on your requirement(s)-:

- [`viewWillAppear(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621510-viewwillappear):

> Notifies the view controller that its view is about to be added to a
>   view hierarchy.

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    // ...
}
```

Or

- [`viewDidAppear(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621423-viewdidappear):

> Notifies the view controller that its view was added to a view
>   hierarchy.

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    // ...
}
```

Note that both of these methods will also be executed when the view controller has been presented/pushed, not only after being dismissed/popped.

In your case, you would need to know if **View Controller B** is disappearing or has disappeared. For this purpose, you could also implement one of the `UIViewController` methods -also -depends on your requirement(s)-:

- [`viewWillDisappear(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621485-viewwilldisappear):

> Notifies the view controller that its view is about to be removed from
>   a view hierarchy.

Or

- [`viewDidDisappear(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621477-viewdiddisappear):

> Notifies the view controller that its view was removed from a view
>   hierarchy.

---

Thus, assuming that the current presented view controller is view controller B and it will be dismissed, the hierarchy of combining the call of the methods between the two view controllers should be as follows:

View Controller **B** => `viewWillDisappear(_:)`.

View Controller **A** => `viewWillAppear(_:)`.

View Controller **B** => `viewDidDisappear(_:)`.

View Controller **A** => `viewDidAppear(_:)`.

Comment: Thanks you Ahmad F

Comment: @SachinthaUdara Glad to help :)